# If $\tau$ is a stopping time, then $f(\tau)$ is also a stopping time.

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes, stopping-times

I have been reading about stopping times and have a question about the composition of stopping times with a measurable function.

Let $f:\mathbb{R}_+\to\mathbb{R}_+$ be any measurable function with $f(t)\geq t$. If $\tau$ is a stopping time, is $f(\tau)$ also a stopping time?

In his [blog](https://almostsuremath.com/2009/11/15/stopping-times-and-the-debut-theorem/), George Lowther says this should be a stopping time. However, I am not sure why this is. Well, clearly, $f(\tau)$ is a well-defined measurable function and we have $\{f(\tau)\leq t\}\subseteq \{\tau\leq t\}\in \mathcal{F}_t$. However, we still need to show that $\{f(\tau)\leq t\}\in\mathcal{F}_t$. I am unsure about how to show this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\{f(\tau) \leq t\}=\{\tau \in f^{-1}(-\infty, t]\}$ and $f^{-1}(-\infty, t] \subseteq (-\infty, t] $ because of the hypothesis on $f$.

Hint for the rest of the argument: Consider the collection of all Borel sets $A$ in $(-\infty, t]$  such that $\tau^{-1}(A) \in \mathcal F_t$. This is a $\sigma-$ field and is contains all intervals of the type $(a,b]$ contained in $(-\infty, t]$.

Comment: Yes, what you wrote makes sense. But I am not sure why $f^{-1}(-\infty,t]\in \mathcal{F}_t$. I feel like this should be simple, but I can't make sense of it. Could you explain this as well?

Comment: @ayrton, For each fixed $t$, we know that $$\{\tau\in(-\infty,s]\}\in\mathcal{F}_t \qquad\text{for any $s\leq t$}.$$ Now use [Dynkin's π- theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynkin_system) to show that this implies $$\{\tau\in B\}\in\mathcal{F}_t\qquad\text{for any Borel subset $B$ of $(-\infty,t]$}.$$

Comment: @ayrton I have added more details.